# Green color water coming from laptop's charging point

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

Recently I encountered that bluish/green color water comes from laptop's charging point.

What is reason and solution for that without going to service center??

Image is not clear but you can see the charging point is wet

[image]

Comment: Could do with having a picture of this... Have never come across anything like this...

Comment: Can you add a picture or link? Was this during the monsoons? Do you see any sparking or feel any ungrounded static on the laptop body? I've never seen anything like this before!

Comment: Nothing like that. I will post the image when i reach home. First I thought that green water is coming from charger but not that case, it came from laptop's point where I charge.

Comment: How did the moisture get into the laptop? Bluish Green is copper salts from corrosion. PC boards inside the computer contain a lot of copper...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has any liquid made its way into your laptop at all or been spilled on the machine?

Capacitors generally contain dielectric fluid, but this is not green - its a brown/silver colour depending on its makeup

Battery Acid or similar are an oily grey colour.

Liquid Crystal from your LCD would also not be green unless under some fairly specific electric charge - but would loose the colour once discharged.  Also, this would not be seeping from the battery adapter port and would be extremely noticable as your screen would almost have certainly stopped working.

None of these solutions turn green in fire or under electric shock - so there is no reason at all why you have green fluid coming from your laptop.

The only possible solution that I can think of (although this is **EXTREMELY** unlikely) is that an oil-based or pre-alcohol solution has made its way into the machine, sat there for a while and has sapped some colour from the motherboard (which is typically green).  This would not cause any damage to the machine as neither have any free-moving ions to transport electrical charge.

Comment: Somewhat like bluish color. I will post image after I go home. But I can still run my laptop.

Comment: ok... none of the fluids are blue either! Will wait for the pic.

Comment: Please see the image which I have added.

Comment: the flash has made it difficult to see anything - just looks like a white reflection to me.  Take another pic without flash and I'll see what I can do

Comment: See the pic updated

Comment: Hi, I think liquid has been spilled on your laptop.  I was beginning to think it may be LCD Fluid or ionised battery acid, but the crystalised nature of teh fluid is neither.  Just to rule out batter, remove it an inspect it for damage

Comment: Is it dangerous? I wiped it then also i can see it afterwards

Comment: IF we don;t know what it is, we can't tell you if its dangerous.  it may be worth taking the back panel off your laptop and drying/cleaning it carefully